# Can't add contextual Filter (taxonomy term ID (with depth)) to a View (User)

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

please help me out here:

I can't find a contextual filter by taxonomy term with depth on a view of users and/or profiles. When I make a view of content it can be chosen. I'd like to provide a filter for Regions, so Filter for Europe should result in a List of Users from all over Europe and so on.

The users are associated with a taxonomy term.

Thanks for your help or any suggestions.

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for user object, you cannot use the filter "has taxonomy term". What you will have to do is add the term reference field that you have created to the user object as contextual filter instead.